# neo4j BOLT query does not always work consitently

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher

I'm using BOLT for NEO4j and I have a simple query to find the length between to nodes (start and stop) of arbitrary length

```
stmt = MATCH (n:Month {ID: {start} }),(m:Month {ID: {stop}}),p = shortestPath((n)-[r:nextMonth*..100000]-(m)) RETURN LENGTH(p)
dict = {'start': '201507', 'stop': '201509'}
result = list(session.run(stmt, dict))[0][0]
```

When I use the web interface, the Cypher query gives me back the result of 2 (which is the correct result). When I run the python command, most of the times the result comes out as [](i.e. no value) instead of the value 2. Sometimes it runs fine and sometimes it does not. It puzzles me that it does not give the correct value all the time and that I can run the query manually without a problem.

This is just an extract from a larger code file. I wonder if there is a problem with how sessions are established or closed? The session that I used has the proper type: neo4j.v1.session.Session object at 0x04CCD7F0

Any ideas why this is or for troubleshooting are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found the root cause of my problem.

I used two sessions:

Session1 was there to create the nodes (statement no shown above)
Session2 was to find the length of the path (shown above)

Adding the smallest delay (time.sleep(0.1) between the creation and path query solved the issue.

I have the suspicion that session2 was already being executed while the creation of the nodes was not completed yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try run this:

`result = session.run(stmt, dict).peek()[0]`

All the time when I get a return of "session.run()", I use the method peek() (if the return is just one line). Otherwise it's better use the result with a loop because this return a collection object who helps on performance of your code, and if the result is huge and you convert all that to a list, maybe you will crack your memory with this.

Comment: the problem was elsewhere but the peek statement is useful indeed